# IIS 6 - Access denied message after changing user

Tags: iis, iis-6

I recently changed the user of an app pool to a newly created one, apparently closed from the existing one and I'm getting this error in the event log:

Failed to execute request because the App-Domain could not be created. Error: 0x80070005 Access is denied.

Any ideas? Is this an incorrect username/password or configuration?